# How to grep multiple strings and format it before printing

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a txt file as below:

```
cat file.txt
<Some text here>
<Some text here>
Animal: type=Reptile age=17 s=M val=snake
   Animal Code: 123
   Animal Color: Black
Animal: type=Reptile age=20 s=M val=Lizard
   Animal Code: 200
   Animal Color: light_Brown
<Some text here>
<Some text here>
```

Here, from the file above

1. I want to extract the lines matching pattern1 `Animal: type=Reptile` to pattern2 `Animal Color:`
2. In the extracted lines I want to search for "Code", "val" and "Color"

Currently what i had used is below:

```
awk '/Animal.*Reptile/,/Animal Color:/' file.txt | grep "Animal Code:\|val\|Animal Color:" | awk '{ if ($5 != NULL ) print $5 ; else print $3; }' | tr "=" "\n" | grep -v val
```

The output from this is as below:

```
snake
123
Black
Lizard
200
light_Brown
```

I want the output to be formatted as **Code,val,Color** shown below:

```
123,snake,Black
200,Lizard,light_Brown
```

How to achieve this??

Comment: Your question is not about security; you may want to ask it on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

awk and grep aren't very strong when it comes to multiple lines - they are both best at working one line at a time. Awk can remember something from one line and use it in another, so in your particular case, awk alone can do the job, but it takes a bit of work.

I assume that the order of lines is fixed, so you won't get a 'Animal Color' line before 'Animal Code' for the same animal. Also, val=? is assumed to be the very last thing on the 'Animal:' line.

how about this:

```
awk_prog='
/^Animal: type=Reptile/ { sub(".*val=",""); val=$0 }
/Animal Code: / { code=$NF }
/Animal Color: / { color=$NF ; print code "," val "," color }
'
awk "$awk_prog" file.txt
```

The program is split into multiple lines for clarity, you can put it all on one line, of course.

Comment: Why on earth would you say `awk and grep aren't very strong when it comes to multiple lines - they are both best at working one line at a time.`? That is complete nonsense wrt awk since awk is record-based, not line-based like grep.

Comment: @EdMorton: granted, awk *can* be made to do a lot, if you really know how - but it normally reads one line at a time and applies the given awk program to every line, one at a time. That is its easiest mode of operation and making it work in any other way takes effort. That is why. Maybe it is personal opinion - but I don't use sed or awk for tasks that are not 'line-at-a-time', unless it is the only tool I have.

Comment: Takes effort? You set the Record Separator variable, RS, to whatever separates your records and you're done. What tool are you thinking of that handles multi-line records more easily? Sounds like you just haven't spent much time working with awk, possibly due to having been misinformed at some point. I'm commenting here to make sure others aren't similarly misinformed. You are correct to only use sed for single-line-at-a-time operations, just like grep, and for anything else you should use awk.

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't doubt that there are masters of awk that would make it do anything - but setting "RS=a_very_long_string_etc" that's not the way that it is usually put into use. Not claiming to be an expert but I've seen a fair amount of scripts that use `awk` in my lifetime. Few are as complex as the example I wrote here (or your own, which is about the same size and complexity). If I have to do something more than this - especially multi-line records in a text file, I would usually drop bash/awk/grep and do it all in Python. ...

Comment: ...(cont) I would definitely NOT recommend "RS=something_other_than_LF" to anyone new on SO. Experienced folks like you (and me) that can actually do this and read their scripts with confidence rarely come here to ask questions - they come to answer them. I am tailoring my advice to the level of those that ask - they're just starting to learn.

Comment: I am an expert in awk and you are speaking just from your own limited experience with it. If you'd like to post a Python script for handling multi-line records in a new question I'll be happy to show you how to do it in awk and the result will be clearer, simpler, briefer and probably more efficient and more portable. Certainly a better approach for someone new to text processing with UNIX tools.

Answer (score 0):

This will let you print whatever fields you like in whatever order you like just by their name:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[: =]+"; OFS="," }
/Animal/ {
    sub(/^ +/,"")
    for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) {
        f[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    if (/Color/) {
        print f["Code"], f["val"], f["Color"], f["age"], f["s"], f["type"]
        delete f
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
123,snake,Black,17,M,Reptile
200,Lizard,light_Brown,20,M,Reptile
```

Massage to suit.